# mysql sort by the table a result was found in

Tags: mysql, sql

Is it possible to order a mysql query by the table the result was found in? In other words, when querying multiple tables (`JOIN` and `OR` in the `WHERE` clause) can I prioritize the tables?

Example:

> Table A `names` - Adam, Ashley, Aaron
>
> Table B `names` - Brian, Bill, Barbara

If my query searches all of these tables:

```
SELECT name from names
JOIN A on A.id = names.id
JOIN B on B.id = names.id 
WHERE A.name LIKE '%derp%' OR B.name LIKE '%derp%'
LIMIT 5
```

Now say I want to prioritize Table B, so the results would be:

> Brian, Bill, Barbara, Adam, Ashley

And if I want to prioritize Table A, the results would then be:

> Adam, Ashley, Aaron, Brian, Bill

Answer (score 1):

You can add an `order by`.  For instance for table `B`:

```
order by (B.name LIKE '%derp%') desc
```

MySQL treats a boolean expression as 0 or 1 in an integer context.  So, the match would turn into 1.